# The request failed to run because the batch is aborted when performing bulk insert using EF Utilities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, sqlbulkcopy

I'm trying to perform mass/bulk insert of my data into the DB table like following:

```
EFBatchOperation.For(ctx, ctx.UserTransactions).InsertAll(prepared.Where((i) => ctx.UserTransactions.Where(x => x.SearchedUserID == updatedUser.SearchedUserID).ToList().FindIndex((el) => el.TransactionID == i.TransactionID) == -1).ToList());
```

And at some point (not in all cases) I get an error like this:

```
The request failed to run because the batch is aborted. This can be caused by abort signal sent from client or another request is running in the same session
```

I've tried to increase Timeout from 0.2s in my connection string like this:

```
Timeout=600000;
```

But that doesn't works, I still keep getting this error....

Anyone knows what it might be?

Comment: Have you checked `Database.CommandTimeout` and `ObjectContext.CommandTimeout` property values when doing mass bulk insert query? Which timeout property had been set to 600 seconds?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto As I understand, if no timeout property has been set in connection string, the default one is set to 200 ms ?